# Align text with a slider

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-slider

I have a table structure like this

```
<tr>
    <td>
      Text to move
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
       <div>jQuery slider container is in here<a>slider pointer is in here</a></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

When the slider moves I see the style is updated for the link element by a percentage representing how far to the right it is Ex: `style="left: 11.7647%;"` I want "text to move" to align itself with the slider, and also move by that percentage. Is there any way I can do this? I can add more divs/spans etc. if necessary.

Note: I know how to grab the percentage the slider has moved, the issue is just aligning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already know the percentage, you can set the text to have a left margin of that same percentage:

```
$("#hoverText").css("margin-left", percent + "%");
```

Here's my working test code:

## HTML

```
<table id="layoutTable" style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td>Percent: <span id="percent"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:100%;"><span id="hoverText">Here's Some Text</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:100%;"><div id="slider"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

## JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#slider").slider({
    "slide": function(event, ui) {
      var percent = ui.value;
      $("#percent").html(percent);
      $("#hoverText").css("margin-left", percent + "%");
    }
  });
});
```